# How important is the "wet edge" when painting vinyl siding?

Tags: painting, vinyl-siding

I am going to paint my vinyl siding (to change the color).  Apparently I'm supposed to go all the way across row by row, or a couple rows at a time.  But what if I get interrupted?  Is it okay to complete several rows and then come back to continue painting later on, after the first part has dried?

Also, for the first of the two coats, may I complete a whole section (top to bottom) before going on to the next section, since the second coat will hopefully cover up any vertical lines I might have created?

Comment: Best to go row by row . If I erupted make sure stopping points are staggered to keep the obvious lap marks of stop/start. From occurring in a vertical line

Comment: When painting something as large and uneven as the side of a house, small issues like overlap marks are not going to be noticeable.  It's hard to pick up issues like that outside of painting smooth surfaces like cabinets or furniture.